# unable to remove white space from HTML view with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, scroll, whitespace

I'm having an issue with the template view below. I've added a scrollbar to the "Used in" table at the bottom, however I am getting a lot of whitespace underneath it. When I try removing each div/element one by one the issue seems to come from that table alone.

view.html

```
{% extends "includes/base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">

            <form method="POST">
                <br>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy partform %}
            </form>
            <br>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody>
                {% for comment in partcomments %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ comment }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <form method="POST">
                <br>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy commentForm %}
            </form>
            <div>
                {% for image in images %}
                <img class="center img-responsive" src="{{ image.image.url }}"
                     style="height: 25%"/>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ imageform.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">

                <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Supplier</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for supplier in partsuppliers %}
                    <tr data-href="{% url 'info_supplier' supplier.supplier.id %}">
                        <td>{{ supplier }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-pad" href="{% url 'addpartsupplier' part_id=part_id %}"
               role="button">Add
                Supplier</a>
            <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">

                <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Movements</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for movement in movements %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ movement.history_date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ movement.history_user }}</td>
                        <td>{{ movement.change }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Used in</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for activity in activities %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ activity.group.groupName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ activity.activity.activityName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ activity.qty.quantity__sum }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

I have a custom.css file served in the static folder that is loaded in the base.html as per below. The issue arises only in this view as I've tried removing the base.html and haven't found any overflow issues in my other template views

custom.css

```
.my-custom-scrollbar
{
position: relative;
max-height: 25%;
overflow: auto;
}
.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
display: block;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I think I'm not including something in the CSS. any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Picture added below for clarification. Lots of whitespace that extends to where the table ends without the y scroll.
[image: whitespace below table]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap applies a margin-bottom of 20px to the ".table" class. If you inspect the table in the console - you will be able to see that styling.

[image]

In order to remove this- you will need to over-ride the style rule in your own styling (note that this MUST be after the Bootsrtrap styles are imported).

```
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've edit my original post with a picture. I tried removing the bottom margin to the same effect. The table seems to be maintaining it's full length even when  the scrollbar has been added.